# Не отображаются VK и FB комменты в табах

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, господа знатоки!

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть сайт, на нем раздел "отзывы", в этом разделе несколько div'ов олицетворяющих табы (вкладки). Так вот в одном из этих контейнеров содержится код комментов facebook, а в другом ВКонтакте. Если во всех дивах поставить статичный контент, то вкладки работают без проблем, но когда я в один из табов вставляю код комментов соц.сети, то они тупо не прогружаются и на их месте просто пустое место. Вкладки продолжают работать, но как-будто я ничего не вставлял.

Внимание вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы все работало и переключая вкладки видно было и контактовские и фейсбуковские комменты? Где я ошибся?

CSS не привожу за ненадобностью (имхо)

```
<ul id="tabs">
     <li><a href="#here" name="#tab1">На сайте</a></li>
     <li><a href="#facebook" name="#tab2">FaceBook</a></li>
     <li><a href="#vk" name="#tab3">ВКонтакте</a></li>
     <li><a href="#other" name="#tab4">Другие...</a></li>
 </ul>
<div id="tabcontainer">
    <div id="tab1">
        <p>Отзывы на этом сайте</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        <p>
        ЗДЕСЬ КОД КОММЕНТАРИЕВ FACEBOOK
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
        <p>
        ЗДЕСЬ КОД КОММЕНТАРИЕВ ВКОНТАКТЕ
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4">
        <p>Отзывы из других мест</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetTabs(){
        $("#tabcontainer div").hide();
        $("#tabs a").attr("id","");
    }
    var myUrl = window.location.href;
    var myUrlTab = myUrl.substring(myUrl.indexOf("#"));
    var myUrlTabName = myUrlTab.substring(0,4);
    (function(){
        $("#tabcontainer div").hide();
        $("#tabs li:first a").attr("id","current");
        $("#tabcontainer div:first").fadeIn();
        $("#tabs a").on("click",function(e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
           if ($(this).attr("id") == "current"){
             return
            }
            else{             
            resetTabs();
            $(this).attr("id","current");
            $($(this).attr('name')).fadeIn();
            }
        });
       for (i = 1; i <= $("#tabs li").length; i++) {
          if (myUrlTab == myUrlTabName + i) {
              resetTabs();
              $("a[name='"+myUrlTab+"']").attr("id","current");
              $(myUrlTab).fadeIn();
          }
        }
    })()
</script>
```

UPD: добавил код FaceBook

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://sanek.co/review" data-width="620" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Приведите код апплетов комментариев, там тоже JS, это может быть важно.

Comment: Неужели никто здесь мне не поможет?